# Utilizing char to determine output isnt working

Tags: c++, if-statement, char

I'm trying to make it so when the user inputs either an r or a p a different portion will execute but for some reason it's not recognizing the single character inputs. Its just taking me to the first if statement saying I don't have the right value, then executing for the r regardless of what i enter. Why isn't this working for me? I tried it with both the letter itself and the ascii number for the corresponding letters and each time it does the same thing. Its not even outputting the final statement which says invalid service code try again. My program looks like this. Thanks in advance for your time!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char servicetype;
    int account;
    double minutes;
    double initialCharge;
    double overCharge;
    double day;
    double night;
    double dayrate;
    double nightrate;
    double balance;
    string service;

    cout << "Please enter your account number: ";
    cin >> account;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Please enter your service code: ";
    cin >> servicetype;
    cout << endl;

    if (servicetype != 'r' || 'R' || 'p' || 'P')
    {
        cout << "Invalid service code entered. Please enter a valid service code of P for premium service or R for regular service: ";
        cin >> servicetype;
        cout << endl;
    }

    else if (servicetype == 'r' || 'R')
    {
        service = "regular";

        initialCharge = 10.00;
        overCharge = .2;

        cout << "Please enter the number of minutes the service was used: ";
        cin >> minutes;
        cout << endl;

        balance = initialCharge + (minutes * overCharge);

        cout << "Account number " << account << " with the " << service << " service which was utilized for " << minutes << " minutes and therefore a balance is due of $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << balance << endl;
    }
    else if (servicetype == 'p' || 'P')
    {
        service = "premium";

        initialCharge = 25.00;
        cout << "Please enter the number of minutes which were used between the hours of 6:00 am and 6:00 pm: ";
        cin >> day;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "Please eneter the number of minutes which were used between the hours of 6:00 pm and 6:00 am: ";
        cin >> night;
        cout << endl;

        if (day < 75)
            dayrate = 0;
        else
            dayrate = (day - 75) * .1;

        if (night < 100)
            nightrate = 0;
        else
            nightrate = (night - 100) * .05;

            balance = initialCharge + nightrate + dayrate;

            minutes = day + night;

            cout << "Account number " << account << " with the " << service << " service which was utilized for " << minutes << " minutes and therefore a balance is due of $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << balance << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "An invalid service code was entered, please try again." << endl;


    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand i could use switch instead of if and it might work but i kind of want to know at this point why its not working with if statements

Comment: `||` is an *operator* , which means that it takes inputs and gives an output. The `||` operator takes two inputs, and outputs either `true` or `false`.  You have given inputs of `'r'` and `'R'` to your first `||`. The result of this will be `true` because at least one of the inputs is not false.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare `serviceType` to each letter. As it is, you are basically saying:

"If `serviceType` is not 'r' OR if 'R' ... etc" which evaluates as `true` always, because `'R'` (which gets converted to its number equivalent) evaluates as `true`. It would be similar to saying:

```
if ('R')
{
}
```

You can fix it by comparing `serviceType` to each character:

```
if (serviceType != 'r' && serviceType != 'R' && serviceType != 'p' && serviceType != 'P')
{
}
```

You could simplify it slightly by using [`tolower`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/) (or `toupper`):

```
if (tolower(serviceType) != 'r' && tolower(serviceType) != 'p')
{
}
```

Comment: It should be `tolower((unsigned char)serviceType)`, or `tolower(serviceType, std::locale())`  . [Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower)